# Haskell type definition, => etc

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell using Learn You a Haskell.  On page 54 is an
implementation of take like so:

```
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
take' n _
    | n <= 0 = []
take' _ []   = []
take' n (x:xs) = x : take' (n-1) xs
```

I understand all the code apart from the first line.

The :: part I understand as meaning this is a type definition?

(Num i, Ord i) is a tuple.  The first element of the tuple has to be
numeric, fair enough.  the second param has to be able to be ordered.
The parameter is the same - both are i.  This means that the types
have to be the same?

Why is it not (Num i, Ord j)?  Isn't the 2nd tuple element
referring to the list?  Which could be of any type?

What does => signify?

i -> [a] -> [a] means first parameter is numeric?  2nd param is any
type list, 3rd param is any type list.  So this is saying first param
numeric, 2nd param a list of any type and it returns a list of any
type.  Well that is understandable I suppose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The stuff before the `=>` are *constraints*. `(Num i, Ord i)` isn't really a tuple in the usual sense. It specifies a requirement that type class instances exist for whatever specific type `i` you call the function with.

So what this type signature is actually saying is that the type of `take'` is `i -> [a] -> [a]`, but with the additional restriction that `i` must have `Num` and `Ord` instances, which amounts to requiring that you can do some basic arithmetic (`Num` being short for "numeric" I suppose) and compare which value is larger (`Ord` meaning values of that type have an ordering defined, i.e. you can sort them or such).

In this particular case, the comparison `n <= 0` is what uses `Ord`, while the subtraction and numeric literals use `Num`.

This is covered in [chapter 3 of LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses), and these specific type classes (among others) are mentioned in [the Typeclasses 101 section](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101).

Comment: You imply this, but to make it more precise: the `n <=` part of the comparison uses `Ord`, but in order (heh) to compare against `0`, we require `Num`.  That's what guarantees that the `0` literal can represent something of the same type as `n` (because `0` is really `fromInteger (0 :: Integer)`, where `fromInteger :: Num i => Integer -> i`).

Answer (score 2):

(Num i, Ord i) is not meant to be a tuple. Read the type signature as: take' is a function of the type `i -> [a] -> [a]` where i has to be a type of the typeclasses Num and Ord.

You might want to read the chapter "Typeclasses 101" again.