# Haskell: Difference between (Num a, Ord a) & (Integral a)

Tags: haskell

Both the following declarations work for `replicate' 3 5`. I am not able to understand why you need Num and Ord when Integral would do. The second one was what I came up with and the first one was here - http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion.

What do I lost with just Integral?

1

```
replicate' :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> b -> [b]
replicate' 0 x = []
replicate' n x = x:replicate' (n-1) x
```

2

```
replicate' :: (Integral a) => a -> b -> [b]
replicate' 0 x = []
replicate' n x = x:replicate' (n-1) x
```

Note: I need to give some clarification here after willem's answer below (he understood the question without this clarification). The code in http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion is

```
replicate' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> a -> [a]  
replicate' n x  
    | n <= 0    = []  
    | otherwise = x:replicate' (n-1) x
```

Not what I have mentioned in 1. Willem's reply explains all three snippets.

Also, a related question is available at [Haskell type definition, => etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927000/haskell-type-definition-etc?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm a little bit confused by your question - are you asking why the typeclasses `Ord` and `Num` exist in the first place? Or are you asking why LearnYouAHaskell teaches the first one instead of the second?

Comment: You’re right – `Integral` would be better. `replicate' 3.3 5` shouldn’t do what it does.

Comment: `Integral` implies `Num` and `Ord`.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I am trying to understand the difference.

Answer (score 13):

Haskell always aims to construct the most generic type signature. If we take a look at the implementation:

```
replicate' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> a -> [a]  
replicate' n x  
    | n <= 0    = []  
    | otherwise = x:replicate' (n-1) x
```

We see that the `(<=) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool` function is applied to `n`, and we calculate `n-1` in the recursion (with `(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`). The most generic type signature thus will add a `Num` and `Ord` type constraint on that number.

We thus can call `replicate' 3.1415 1`, and it will return the first four items. But it is probably nonsensical to do that.

The `Integral` typeclass is a typeclass for integral numbers. It supports integer division. Any `Integral` type must be a member of the `Real` and `Enum` typeclass.

A type that is a member of the `Real` typeclass, should support a function `toRational :: Real a => a -> Rational` to convert that number to a `Rational`, and furthermore should be a member of the `Num` and `Ord` typeclasses.

This thus means that if a type is a member of the `Integral` typeclass, it is a member of `Num`, `Enum`, `Ord` and `Real` as well. You thus made the type more *restrictive*. But I think in the context of a `replicate'` it makes perfect sense to do that.

Note that it might *not* be ideal to write:

```
replicate' :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> b -> [b]
replicate' 0 x = []
replicate' n x = x:replicate' (n-1) x
```

In case we here call `replicate (-3) 1`, or `replicate 3.14 1` (as [@leftroundabout pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110296/haskell-difference-between-num-a-ord-a-integral-a/58111467?noredirect=1#comment102629639_58111467)), we will obtain an infinite list of `1`s.

Comment: N.b. in case of the `replicate' 0 x = []` implementation, `replicate' 3.14` would _also_ generate an infinite list!